# LXDE autostart is not working

Tags: lxde, lxterminal

I am trying to execute a simple script `lxterminal -e "/home/pi/superscript.sh"`
 in a normal terminal it works perfectly. But if i try putting it in to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` witch looks like this after this procedure:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
@lxterminal -e "/home/pi/superscript.sh"
```

Nothing happens after start up. What could be the error here?

Comment: Tried it without the @?

Comment: @AndyAnderson Yes.

Comment: How about: sh /home/pi/superscript.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global LXDE autostart file is ignored if there is a local autostart.

In Raspbian there is a local file: `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Adding the command to that file should start it when you log in to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

If using `lxterminal` Don't forget to set the working directory with `--working-directory="/home/pi/somedirectory"`, specially if you try to call some program not in standard path!