# Python script not running on start up

Tags: python, boot

I have edited `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` using `nano` (without `sudo`) to open a lxterminal and run a simple python script that contains an infinite while loop with a print statement.

In my autostart file I have the following command:

`@lxterminal -e python3 ~/Desktop/t.py`

However, whenever I boot into Desktop environment, I see a lxterminal window pop up for a split second then disappear.

When I also add `@lxterminal -e python3 -v` into the `autostart` file, it runs perfectly and the lxterminal window stays there.

I have changed t.py to have one line: print('hello'). The result is the same. A terminal window will open for a split second then close. I don't believe a print statement should cause an exception.

Does anyone know what could be causing my issue?

Thanks

Comment: change the `t.py` so that it will run without error in python 2.7 and try rebooting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LXDE autostart is not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89519/lxde-autostart-is-not-working)

Comment: I have changed t.py to have one line: `print('hello')`. The result is the same. A terminal window will open for a split second then close. I don't believe a print statement should cause an exception.

Comment: Post your code. Maybe your infinite loop is not as infinite as you think.

Answer (score 2):

With `lxterminal -e python3` you are starting the python3 interpreter and it prompts you with `>>>`. It is still running until you quit it with `<Ctrl>D`. Then the lxterminal will also close. Your `hello` script just prints it and terminates and with it also lxterminal. That is what you see but it is too short to realize the **hello** output. For testing make your t.py as following:

```
from time import sleep
print('hello world')
while True:
    sleep(60)
```

with the endless `while` loop the script does not terminate and will stay in lxterminal until you interrupt it with `<Ctrl>C`. Then lxterminal also closes.

Comment: The OP claims that they have an "infinite while loop with a print statement". In my understanding, an infinite loop cannot be too short.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I refer to the comment only using `print('hello')`. You have already commented it. I have edit the question and add the comment to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the local autostart file:

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add the following with full paths to python3 and your code:

```
@lxterminal -e /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/t.py
```